# Automatic search and retrieval with VLOOKUP and SEARCH

Tags: excel, search, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have the following Excel issue: In `Sheet 1` I have a range of items that have a word within each cell that I want to search in a list in `Sheet 2`. I don't want to specify the word I want the formula to check what words are the same in `Sheet 1` and `Sheet 2` automatically.

**Sheet 1**

```
Item List
---------
Mums card
Dads card
Daddy card
```

**Sheet 2**

```
Column A       Column B
--------       --------      
Mum             Home
Dad             Away
Daddy           Away
```

What I need to achieve is the following:

Automatically search for the word `"mum"` in cell `A1` in `Sheet 1` (item list) and check that it is there in the list in `Sheet 2` and return the value to the right of it.

I thought `VLOOKUP` and `SEARCH` but not sure how to start that. It will also need to return blank if nothing is found.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 1):

Using your example, in Sheet1 cell B2 and copied down:

```
=IF(AND(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3&"*"))=0,A2<>""),"",INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$3,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3&"*")>0,),0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

For simplicity, I have brought your data onto one sheet - but it should be easy enough to split it out (just change the formula references)

the formula for cell **B1** is:

```
{=INDEX($E$1:$E$3,MAX(IFERROR(FIND($D$1:$D$3,$A1)*ROW($D$1:$D$3),0)))}
```

Leave out the curly braces and enter the function using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Image below:

[image]